# clang format line break in the wrong place

Tags: c++, clang-format

Given the following line of code:

```cpp
get_abc_manager().get_platform_status(abc_platform_status, sw_update_status, fill_update_status, actions_allowed_status);
```

I want clang format to break the line on the parameters like - which is what it does in most places (for basic function calls)

```cpp
get_abc_manager().get_platform_status(
    abc_platform_status, 
    sw_update_status, 
    fill_update_status, 
    actions_allowed_status);
```

But, I think, because it's got the "." to access the returned abc_managers function `get_platform_status()` it seems to use that as a line to break on so I get:

```cpp
get_abc_manager().
    get_platform_status(abc_platform_status, sw_update_status, fill_update_status, actions_allowed_status);
```

Line length limit is 120 - so if the params got any longer then it probably would break over the params. In fact, I tried that:

```cpp
get_abc_manager().get_platform_status(
    abc_platform_status,
    sw_update_stadddddddddddddddddddddddddtus,
    fill_update_status,
    actions_allowed_status);
```

So it's just this "middle" case I don't like where it shortens the line by breaking after the dot before breaking the param list.

Is there a way to prefer breaking the line on the parameters first?

**update:** clang-format version 10.0.0-4ubuntu1~18.04.2

```js
---
Language:        Cpp
# BasedOnStyle:  WebKit
AccessModifierOffset: -4
AlignAfterOpenBracket: AlwaysBreak
AlignConsecutiveMacros: false
AlignConsecutiveAssignments: false
AlignConsecutiveDeclarations: false
AlignEscapedNewlines: Right
AlignOperands:   false
AlignTrailingComments: false
AllowAllArgumentsOnNextLine: false
AllowAllConstructorInitializersOnNextLine: false
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: false
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: false
# Don't allow function on one line, e.g. 'int f() {return 1;}' - unless its inline
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: InlineOnly
AllowShortLambdasOnASingleLine: All
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: Never
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: false
AlwaysBreakAfterDefinitionReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings: false
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: MultiLine
BinPackArguments: false
BinPackParameters: false
BraceWrapping:
  AfterCaseLabel:  true
  AfterClass:      true
  AfterControlStatement: true
  AfterEnum:       true
  AfterFunction:   true
  AfterNamespace:  true
  AfterObjCDeclaration: true
  AfterStruct:     true
  AfterUnion:      true
  AfterExternBlock: true
  BeforeCatch:     true
  BeforeElse:      true
  IndentBraces:    true
  SplitEmptyFunction: true
  SplitEmptyRecord: true
  SplitEmptyNamespace: true
# have line breaks after operators: 'if (a ||' instead of on the next line ' || b'
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: None
BreakBeforeBraces: Allman
BreakBeforeInheritanceComma: false
BreakInheritanceList: BeforeColon
BreakBeforeTernaryOperators: true
BreakConstructorInitializersBeforeComma: false
BreakConstructorInitializers: BeforeComma
BreakAfterJavaFieldAnnotations: false
BreakStringLiterals: true
# effectively the line length limit before clang-format starts to use multiple lines
ColumnLimit:     120
CommentPragmas:  '^ IWYU pragma:'
CompactNamespaces: false
ConstructorInitializerAllOnOneLineOrOnePerLine: false
ConstructorInitializerIndentWidth: 4
ContinuationIndentWidth: 4
# format braces lists (uniform init) like a function param list
Cpp11BracedListStyle: true
DeriveLineEnding: true
DerivePointerAlignment: false
DisableFormat:   false
ExperimentalAutoDetectBinPacking: false
FixNamespaceComments: false
ForEachMacros:
  - foreach
  - Q_FOREACH
  - BOOST_FOREACH
IncludeBlocks:   Preserve
IncludeCategories:
  - Regex:           '^"(llvm|llvm-c|clang|clang-c)/'
Priority:        2
SortPriority:    0
  - Regex:           '^(<|"(gtest|gmock|isl|json)/)'
Priority:        3
SortPriority:    0
  - Regex:           '.*'
Priority:        1
SortPriority:    0
IncludeIsMainRegex: '(Test)?$'
IncludeIsMainSourceRegex: ''
IndentCaseLabels: true
IndentGotoLabels: true
IndentPPDirectives: None
IndentWidth:     4
IndentWrappedFunctionNames: false
JavaScriptQuotes: Leave
JavaScriptWrapImports: true
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: true
MacroBlockBegin: ''
MacroBlockEnd:   ''
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 1
NamespaceIndentation: Inner
ObjCBinPackProtocolList: Auto
ObjCBlockIndentWidth: 4
ObjCSpaceAfterProperty: true
ObjCSpaceBeforeProtocolList: true
PenaltyBreakAssignment: 2
PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter: 19
PenaltyBreakComment: 300
PenaltyBreakFirstLessLess: 120
PenaltyBreakString: 1000
PenaltyBreakTemplateDeclaration: 10
PenaltyExcessCharacter: 1000000
PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine: 60
# 'int *p' instead of 'int* p;'
PointerAlignment: Right
ReflowComments:  true
SortIncludes:    true
SortUsingDeclarations: true
SpaceAfterCStyleCast: false
SpaceAfterLogicalNot: false
SpaceAfterTemplateKeyword: true
SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: true
SpaceBeforeCpp11BracedList: true
SpaceBeforeCtorInitializerColon: true
SpaceBeforeInheritanceColon: true
SpaceBeforeParens: ControlStatements
SpaceBeforeRangeBasedForLoopColon: true
SpaceInEmptyBlock: true
SpaceInEmptyParentheses: false
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 1
SpacesInAngles:  false
SpacesInConditionalStatement: false
SpacesInContainerLiterals: true
SpacesInCStyleCastParentheses: false
SpacesInParentheses: false
SpacesInSquareBrackets: false
SpaceBeforeSquareBrackets: false
Standard:        Latest
StatementMacros:
  - Q_UNUSED
  - QT_REQUIRE_VERSION
TabWidth:        8
UseCRLF:         false
UseTab:          Never
...
```

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the behavior using any of the default styles in VS2019 could you edit to include the content of your `.clang-format` file?

Comment: @Fiskmans - I added my clang format file (in the code snippet) if that helps?